# Can you import data into an Access database using only the runtime environment?

Tags: ms-access, import, runtime-environment

I have developed an Access database for a small business and wish to create a way of adding new entries remotely, I am not sure how exactly, but I'd like to know if there is a way to import data if said business is utilizing access only with the runtime environment which doesn't provide any of the "menu buttons" of the main product, among which there are several import options (excel, access, xml etc...).

Alternatively, would it be possible to hook up the databse with an external source from which it will pull new entries periodically?

Comment: This question is way too broad. Of course you can import from files and/or use an external data source. Please ask a specific question if you want a specific answer (and if not, ask somewhere else)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I'm just looking for someone to point me in the right direction, it seems to me like the runtime environment of access is very restricting and I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the runtime environment hides a lot of the functionality in Access, but almost anything that can be done with a full version of Access can be done in the runtime environment, including imports and exports.

In your case, you will want to look into the VBA methods DoCmd.TransferText, DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet, and DoCmd.TransferDatabase. You will need to create a button or a menu item in the runtime environment to call a custom VBA method where the appropriate DoCmd.Transfer* method is called with parameters you will have to supply from your custom user interface or values stored in your database.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it would be something of the sort. I'll look into the methods you mentioned.